# How to select number of colors when exporting in PNG8?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cc-2019

Photoshop CC 2019.

I do `Export As...`, select PNG, select Smaller File. And then I'm unable to set color number. Probably, Photoshop uses 256 colors. Is there any way to set the value to 16 or 32? Looks like this export dialog was designed for instagram users :(

I'd love to use good old `Save For Web` option, but it doesn't work for me anymore. When I press Save it throws:

> Could not complete this operation. An unknown error has occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can not set the color amount when saving, do it before at the application.

Menu **Image** → **Mode** → **Indexed Color** and set the colors number

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try to export indexed color image, the transparent background becomes white. `Transparency` is ticked on in both Indexed Color dialog and Export dialog